# DataFrame: datetime column to int type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, int

I am working with DataFrames, and created a new datetime column ('time_diff') from two other columns. I now need to convert the new 'time_diff' column into an int column, counting days.

I've tried .astype(int), this was unsuccessful.

This is my code:

```
# Preprocessing start and end dates
from datetime import datetime

train_plus = train_full.copy()

# Replace all last_event_DI 'unk' with corresponding start_time_DI
for i in range(len(train_plus)): # Makes a range from 0 to #-1, this is needed to loop over the length
    if (train_plus['last_event_DI'][i] == 'unk'):
        train_plus['last_event_DI'][i] = train_plus['start_time_DI'][i]

# Last interaction - start date = length of interaction (time_diff)
train_plus['time_diff'] = train_plus['last_event_DI'].apply(pd.to_datetime) - train_plus['start_time_DI'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# I need the 'time_diff' column to become an int column
# CONVERSION CODE HERE

train_plus
```

Here's a screenshot of code and dataframe below:

[Screenshot of my code and DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJfvf.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you do:

```
train_plus['time_diff'] = train_plus['time_diff'].days
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered. Simple solution:

```
# Replace all time_diff time_deltas with int
for i in range(len(train_plus)): # Makes a range from 0 to #-1, this is needed to loop over the length
    train_plus['time_diff'][i] = train_plus['time_diff'][i].days
```